# SQL query - If row in table1 has value, return else don't

Tags: mysql, sql, union, any

I have a query which returns each row from a table called `posts`, I have now added photos to the posts so when a user uploads a new photo it will create a row in the posts which then shows the new photo uploaded. I have this all working, the issue is when a user deletes the photo, I don't want that row to be returned from posts.

This is what I've got thus far, it returns all rows still.

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p WHERE p.toID='$id' AND p.state='0' AND


(
    (
        p.type = '2' AND
        p.post = ANY (SELECT ph.id FROM photos ph WHERE ph.state='0' AND ph.id=p.post)
    ) 
    OR 
    (
        p.type!='2' //I had to add this because it wasn't returning any other posts types 
                        //if there weren't any of the `type=2`, how could I also fix that?
    )
)

ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

So what it needs to check in order to know to return the `post` row is whether `ph.state` is equal to 0, if it's not equal to 0 then it means the photo has been removed.

**Edit**

Also is there a way to force `p.post` to be an `intval`? The column in the database is a varchar because normally it stores a text based post

Table Structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `albumID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=651 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `toID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fromID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post` longtext NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=380 ;
```

Comment: Could you please post table structure

Answer (score 0):

where u have  `'0'` change it to `0` without quotes

where u have  `'2'` change it to `2` without quotes

edit:

to make it interval just do like that

p.type < somenumber and p.type > someothernumver

Comment: Thanks, also could you check out my edit to see if you could help with that too? I was unable to find that in Google.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean like, well in PHP I use `intval(post)`

Comment: ahh intval not interval :). why not change your column to INT ?instead of varchar

Comment: Ah oops, I didn't mean to type interval! haha. Well because the primary use of the `post` column is for status updates. I am just using it for numbers (photo IDs) when the type=2, otherwise is for text.

Comment: if in php yes u can use it intval() , and in sql u can use `(CAST('2' AS INTEGER))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* 
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN photos ph ON p.post  = ph.id AND ph.state = 0 
WHERE p.toID='$id' AND p.state = 0 AND 
        ((ph.id IS NULL AND p.type = 2) OR p.type != 2) 
ORDER BY p.id DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Well, I just saw the reason it had the error, it was because of `p.posts` is suppose to be `p.post` however with that fixed it just returns every row of the deleted photos as well, but my query above actually does work how i want it to it turns out, other than the second part after the "OR" where i have to declare p.type!=2

Comment: That returns like double the rows as before, hah. (of the removed photos ones)

Comment: Try one more time with adding distinct and typeid !=2

Comment: Eh no it's still returning the rows :\ I appreciate your effort though! Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's returning the rows from photos table which have a state of 1, even though you have it coded for 0 so I'm not sure why that's happening.

Comment: Check my updated answer. if it won't work than provide me the sqlfiddle demo or sample data on which I can check what's the issue you were facing?